# PDF to image inside Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, png

We have an application in Google AppEngine environment and we need to convert a PDF file to PNG image.

Does anybody know a solution that will work in GAE environment?
Does anybody have success experience with free solutions?
Can anybody recommend some commercial solution?

We have tried PDFRenderer - it's free and works usually, but looks like it's no longer supported, and it has troubles with some documents.

There is PDFBox and Ghostscript but they don't have an API, there is just command line tool. It's can be used, but we have an opinion that using of command line tool can leads to problems with performance. Does anybody have some experience with them?

There is PDFImages powered by Qoppa Software, we plan to use it if doesn't find any free solution. Does anybody have experience with it?

Also, there is an idea to do it with Google Drive. There is an ability to save file and export it in preferred format. What do you think about it?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/PDFToImage.java

Comment: I know the above link will not be useful to you. But what about adding the whole source code of pdfbox, and use the above class to accomplish your task? I know it is not a good solution

Comment: I think it's not so bad solution and in many case will work good, but generating png image from pdf document is base function of out app, and we need really good sollution for it. Any way thanks for you atention.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented earlier, import whole source code to your project and use PDFToImage.java to convert pdf to image is one solution for you. Using pdfbox you can convert pdf to jpeg or png format. You can add png as parameter or edit the class PDFToImage, to create png image as default (But it is not a good solution in your case).

As per me, to convert pdf to image, the best tool is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It is more faster and reliable than PDFBox. I think ImageMagick also provide APIs. Please check [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) and check whether it is useful to you.